# How should one introduce automation testing to a software which is already in production?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, end-to-end

How should one introduce automation testing for a software (Android & iOS) which is already in production? Such software was only undergoing user acceptance testing (manually) which was being done manually. Since the system is already built, which would be the most efficient approach to introduce automation testing? From where should one start? Which types of testing would one ideally start with? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're in situation where the traditional approach won't work, my suggestion is to reverse it. The automation tests require stable and separate environment to run (assuming you won't test on your local PC), so assuring the  QA one is the first step in achieving

> introduce automation testing

Moving your prod code to lower environment will give you a chance to build a pipeline, my assumption is that future development will be taken and that's why you're facing this scenario.

Regarding

> Which types of testing would one ideally start with

once you have your QA env a [Smoke testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software)) will give you first results and if used for every deploy/release will guard you from broken env or deploys.  Another major part is the [Integration testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing), it'll verify functional, performance, and reliability requirements. I'm assuming the code has already passed Unit testing. After the development is in active state again, next logical step is to go with the [Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing), will give you enough confidence in the product's new features.

Since this will be a significant automation effort - a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) process and server should be put to work. Here you can chain the Smoke suite. You can take a look at [circleci](https://circleci.com/mobile) or [greenhouseci](http://greenhouseci.com/) for your case

> automation testing for a software (Android & iOS)

Achieving above said, it's actually up to business to decide how much testing is enough. Do they need security, performance, usability etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically there is no unit testing ....the only thing there is so far is manual UAT. Concerning automation I do not know whether it would be worth it to go through unit/integration/system/acceptance testing ....or through end to end. The app is medical....and should I take one of these routes ...where would I start?

Comment: Since it's life concerning app, the critical safety is #1 thing you should always keep in mind. My advice is to *keep the manual UAT*. In the majority of cases I'd stick with just unit and E2E, but in this case testing never seems enough.

Comment: Can u be more specific about what exactly the app is doing? Is it X-ray like, or mesures blood pressure? Depending from that, we could try to build a test strategy.